# Remove a single instance of object dulplicates in an array inside JavaScript

Tags: javascript, lodash

Let's say I have a structure like so...

```
let data = [
  { id: "Ik6e" },
  { id: "H0uD" },
  { id: "E^di" },
  { id: "Ik6e" },
  { id: "Ik6e" },
];
```

And I want to remove one instance of an object with the `id` of `Ik6e` (does not matter which one).
My desire for a new `data` value is...

```
[
  { id: "Ik6e" },
  { id: "H0uD" },
  { id: "E^di" },
  { id: "Ik6e" },
]
```

Since my project utilizes Lodash, would it be possible to achieve this with Lodash at all? If not, vanilla JS would be just fine.

Comment: @trincot One will be removed and the other two will remain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `filter` so to create a new array. Keep a count down for each id that starts at 1, and exclude the id when its count down value is 0 (falsy). This will always kick out the *second* occurrence of the same id.

```js
let data = [{ id: "Ik6e" }, { id: "H0uD" },{ id: "E^di" },{ id: "Ik6e" },{ id: "Ik6e" }];

let count = {};
let result = data.filter(({id}) => count[id] = (count[id]??2) - 1);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Could the downvoter explain why they find this answer is not useful?

Comment: First of all, thanks for all the help so far. I implemented your solution and found it to be a great start. However, it also removes an instance of other duplicates. For example, if there are three objects of  `{ id: "H0uD" }`, it removes one instance of that as well instead of removing only one instance of `{ id: "Ik6e" }`

Comment: Yes, I thought that is what you wanted: to detect all those that occur more than once, and of all those to remove one of those duplicates.

Comment: Oh no, it's great! Thank you so much once again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const removeOneItem = (list, target) => {
  const targetIndex = list.findIndex(item => item.id === target);
  list.splice(targetIndex, 1)
}
  
removeOneItem(data, 'Ik6e');
```

Comment: I think the point is to perform the operation without knowing in advance the duplicated ID or event if a duplicated ID exists

Comment: I don't understand your point. @secan. OP wants to remove 1 item with a specific id (knowing some dups) and the code above works.

Comment: You hardcoded a target. But what if the array has a duplicate id equal to "abc"? And maybe several ids that occur duplicate? You'll need to *find* which ids are actually occurring more than once. You cannot assume beforehand that it will be a specific one.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the post (or i do). "And I want to remove one instance of an object with the id of "Ik6e" (does not matter which one)." - I think this mean OP knows which one to remove.

Comment: I think that was just intended as an *example*. If that was the *only* case they were interested in, they would just hard-code their array without that value from the start.

Comment: if it's an example, why the result is to keep 2 duplicate values, not just 1?

Comment: @vuongvu because the specifications requested by the OP are to delete *only one* duplicated occurencies, not all of them. We must assume the OP has his/her reason to want that.

Comment: @secan I have no concern about OP's request. The code does what I think OP asked.

Comment: @vuongvu I am not sure about how this entire site can work if we all "*have no concern about the OP's request*"; isn't the point to help others with their requests?

Comment: @secan "We must assume the OP has his/her reason to want that." -> I mean I have no problem thinking why they asked the question, don't take it negatively, we all spend time here learning from others, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure there must be an easier / more linear solution, but this should work:

```js
const data = [
  { id: "Ik6e" },
  { id: "H0uD" },
  { id: "E^di" },
  { id: "Ik6e" },
  { id: "Ik6e" },
];

function removeLastDuplicate(arr) {
  // 1. create an object to store all indexes of items with the same ID
  const itemIdIndexes = arr.reduce((acc, item, index) => {
    if (Object.keys(acc).indexOf(item.id) === -1) {
      acc = {
        ...acc,
        [item.id]: [index]
      };
    } else {
      acc[item.id].push(index);
    }

    return acc
  }, {});

  // 2. find the indexes of the items to be deleted
  const indexesToDelete = Object.values(itemIdIndexes)
    .filter(item => item.length > 1) // filter only duplicated IDs
    .map(item => item[item.length - 1]) // store the last index of duplicated IDs

  // 3. return a copy of the original array, with the last occurrence of duplicated items deleted
  return arr.filter((item, index) => indexesToDelete.indexOf(index) === -1);
}

const dataModified = removeLastDuplicate(data)

console.log('data:', data);
console.log('dataModified:', dataModified);
```

If you prefer to remove the first occurrence instead of the last one, you can replace:

```js
      // 2. find the indexes of the items to be deleted
      const indexesToDelete = Object.values(itemIdIndexes)
        .filter(item => item.length > 1) // filter only duplicated IDs
        .map(item => item[item.length - 1])
```

with:

```js
      // 2. find the indexes of the items to be deleted
      const indexesToDelete = Object.values(itemIdIndexes)
        .filter(item => item.length > 1) // filter only duplicated IDs
        .map(item => item[0])
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution! Tried it out and it worked great! I decided to up vote the above solution by @trincot because it is short and simple.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
let data = [
  { id: "Ik6e" },
  { id: "H0uD" },
  { id: "E^di" },
  { id: "Ik6e" },
  { id: "Ik6e" },
]; 
let newData = [] 

data.forEach(ele=>{
     if(newData.indexOf(ele.id) === -1){
         newData.push(ele)
     }
})
console.log(newData)
```

Let me know if it works